# Gradle: How to have an upload task make an up-to-date check?

Tags: gradle

I'm trying something rather simple: not having an upload task execute a second time for the same version number. I

```
uploadArchives {
    inputs.file file("version.txt")
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And version.txt contains:

```
1.0.2
```

However, the task is not show as UP-TO-DATE when I execute the task twice without changing version. I also tried declaring a property as input, to the same effect.
I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: input files has never worked properly for me, but properties do. You could try `input property 'archive_version' file('version.txt').getText('UTF-8')` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Upload` task type doesn't declare any outputs, in which case Gradle plays it safe and assumes that outputs are out-of-date. Try this:

```
uploadArchives.outputs.upToDateWhen { true }
```

Now the `uploadArchives` task should be up-to-date unless either the version file or the contents of the archives to be uploaded have changed (compared to the previous execution of the task on the same machine). The archive contents are declared as an input by the `Upload` task type.

Note that this won't prevent user/build A from uploading the same version as was uploaded by user/build B. To achieve that, you'd have to implement a local/remote version comparison in `outputs.upToDateWhen {}`.

Another option is to enforce the "do not override" rule on the repository side.

Comment: As the author of the question, you would typically just accept an answer (as you already did). Not even sure if you can vote for answers to your own question.

Comment: Seems I was a bit eager with accepting the answer. Unfortunately it doesn't quite work that way. I put more details in the question.

Comment: Finally figured out why it wasn't working on Jenkins. It was still running Gradle 1.1. Oh the joy with reluctant updating...

Comment: Not using the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html)?